# Docker Image Not Loading on Localhost. Network, etc

Tags: docker, networking

I have been having really hard time figuring out the problem with my docker image not loading on localhost. I am using Docker for Windows 7. Following is some information regarding my docker image, network, etc, if it can be any helpful in proposing solutions.

I have `EXPOSE 80` in my docker file. and `listen 8080` in my shinyserver.conf file. I run my image by typing `docker run -p 80:8080 imagename`. It goes back to command line. Then I check http://localhost or http://localhost:8080, or http://172.17.0.1 or http://172.17.0.1:8080 or http://192.168.99.100 and no image shows up.

When I run `docker ps` there is no running container (makes sense, since image is not running anyway on localhost). All exited containers show with `docker ps -a`. There some containers that I haven't even created by show (i guess it comes with creating images).

I run docker inspect to find the IP address and here is what I get (there is no IP on fitfarmz which is my imagename)

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(docker ps -aq)

/mystifying_johnson -
/wonderful_newton -
/flamboyant_brown -
/gallant_austin -
/fitfarmz-2 -
/fitfarmz -
/amazing_easley -
/nervous_lewin -
/silly_wiles -
/lucid_hopper -
/quizzical_kirch -
/boring_gates -
/clever_booth -
/determined_mestorf -
/pedantic_wozniak -
/goofy_goldstine -
/sharp_ardinghelli -
/xenodochial_lamport -
/keen_panini -
/blissful_lamarr -
/suspicious_boyd -
/confident_hodgkin -
/vigorous_lewin - 172.17.0.2
/quirky_khorana -
/agitated_knuth -
```

I also got info on docker network:

```
$ docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "9105bd8d679ad2e7d814781b4fa99f375cff3a99a047e70ef63e463c35c5ae28"
,
        "Created": "2018-09-08T22:22:51.075519268Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM r-base:3.5.0

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev 


# Add shiny user
RUN groupadd  shiny \
&& useradd --gid shiny --shell /bin/bash --create-home shiny



# Download and install ShinyServer
RUN wget --no-verbose https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb && \
    gdebi shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb


# Install R packages that are required
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('Benchmarking', 'plotly', 'DT'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app /srv/shiny-server/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Copy further configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

And shinyserver.conf:

```
# Define the user we should use when spawning R Shiny processes
run_as shiny;

# Define a top-level server which will listen on a port
server {
  # Instruct this server to listen on port 80. The app at dokku-alt need expose PORT 80, or 500 e etc. See the docs
  listen 8080;

  # Define the location available at the base URL
  location / {

    # Run this location in 'site_dir' mode, which hosts the entire directory
    # tree at '/srv/shiny-server'
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Define where we should put the log files for this location
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # Should we list the contents of a (non-Shiny-App) directory when the user 
    # visits the corresponding URL?
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

Here is the shiny-server.sh file:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/shiny-server
chown shiny.shiny /var/log/shiny-server

exec shiny-server >> /var/log/shiny-server.log 2>&1
```

Any ideas what is going wrong? I use the command: `docker run -p 80:8080 fitfarmz` to run the image.

Comment: If you run `docker run` without `-d`, and immediately get a command prompt back, your container exited.

Comment: What is the reason that it exited? And how to make sure that it doesn't exit? Thanks.

Comment: Please add up the Dockerfile and the exact command using for running container. That would help.

Comment: Sure. I have provided the dockerfile and shinyserver.conf

Comment: @ZiaW Is /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh a permanent bash script? It must be, otherwise the container would exit immediately since the CMD instruction indicating so.

Comment: @Light.G, I don't have the expertise to know whether it is permanent or not. I just followed a guide to create the dockerfile. When I pass the command `docker run -p 80:8080 fitfarmz`, it returns to command prompt immediately which is the problem.

Comment: @ZiaW Maybe it’s the issue. Could u pls add up shiny-server.sh and logs for fitfarmz(docker logs container-name)?

Comment: @Light.G, I have provided shiny-server.sh in the main question. I got nothing when trying to access docker logs. I tried with container name, container ID, image name. I used this command previously to get a running container, `$ docker run -d -t -i fitfarmz /bin/bash` and it shows in `docker ps` but seems it didn't really help. really appreciate you looking into this.

Comment: @ZiaW Delete  “>> /var/log/shiny-server.log 2>&1”, try again.

Comment: @Light.G, you mean to delete that part and update the image afterward, and then check whether the image runs?

Comment: @ZiaW yes, since it’s a change in image, so u must re-build image. And try to run a container from it.

Comment: @Light.G, I recreated my image and when i docker run the image, this is what i get as an error message: "/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh: 7: exec: shiny-server: not found".

Comment: @ZiaW Follow the steps: 1. docker run -tid —-name shiny-server fitfarmz /bin/bash  2. docker exec -ti shiny-server /bin/bash  3. Find the executable file shiny-server. 4. Add the absolute path of shiny-server to shiny-server.sh  5. Re-build image and try again.

Comment: @Light.G, I complete 1 and 2 successfully but I don't know how to find the absolute path of executable shiny-server. After step 2, when I enter `root@53864ba7a586:/# dir`, I get following output: 
`bin   etc   lib32   media  proc  sbin                              sys  var
boot  home  lib64   mnt    root  shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb  tmp
dev   lib   libx32  opt    run   srv                               usr`  . And once I find the absolute path, should I add to shiny-server.conf like this: `exec shiny-server absolute path`   ??

Comment: @ZiaW what’s the absolute path of shiny-server?

Comment: @Light.G, should I type this to find the absolute path: `find "$(pwd -P)" -name "shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb"`  ?

Comment: @ZiaW find / -name shiny-server

Comment: @Light.G, I get two absolute paths, 1)  /etc/shiny-server
2) /srv/shiny-server. which one should i use. And should I use it like this in shiny-server.sh file: `exec shiny-server /etc/shiny-server`. Thanks.

Comment: @ZiaW Make sure shiny-server is executable, then change to “exec /absolute_path/to/shiny-server”.

Comment: @Light.G, sorry for lack of my knowledge. How do I make sure shiny-server is executable. Before I build my image, I will include the “exec /absolute_path/to/shiny-server” code in shiny-server.sh and then start image building process. Shiny-sever will be installed because it is mentioned in dockerfile. Is there another specific step or code that I should perform before building a new image. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ZiaW Yes, you might prepare lots of basis for real. I think maybe you ought to install and configure shiny-server on bare machine first, then try containerize it again.

Comment: @Light.G, thanks for your help all this time. I finally fixed my problems. Somehow shiny-server was not getting installed from gdebi, so I fixed that. Your posts helped me to understand that the main issue was with shiny-server executable. If I didn't know that, i would not know how to proceed for a solution. THanks.

Comment: @ZiaW , it’s a pleasure. We all could get better understanding while trying to figure out the problems troubling people.